# Hiding the excels working with macro

Tags: excel, vba, hide, visibility

I want to hide the excels while macros working on them. Application.visible is not working i don't know why. Is it possible for me to just write a code at the beginning so that until the end the excels won't be visible. Minimization is also works for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling it correctly? i.e.

```
Application.Visible = False
```

Alternatively you could 'freeze' the screen so you don't see anything whilst the macro is operating using:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, i think every time  macro creates a workbook i need to rewrite these codes after it. That was the problem I guess. Do you know any way to hide other applications such as SAP? Macro uses it but I couldn't minimize it

Comment: @hakandeep no I don't, given it's scope you should probably ask that as a new SO question for more exposure.

Answer (score 0):

I see `Application.Visible` is working fine for me.

I tried below code. I triggered below code on button click.

The Excel sheet is not displayed only excel icon was available on task bar.

```
Sub test()

Application.Visible = False
Cells(1, 1) = "Testing Visibility"
MsgBox "testing visibility"
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.Visible = True


End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, i think every time  macro creates a workbook i need to rewrite these codes after it. That was the problem I guess. Do you know any way to hide other applications such as SAP? Macro uses it but I couldn't minimize it